# PHP, SQL, вывод данных с таблицы в конкретный элемент

Tags: php, sql

Вопрос: можно ли вывести данные с SQL таблицы в див с определенной id?

Знаю, данные можно выводить таким образом:

```
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo "<td>". $row['photo']."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
    }
```

И вот я пыталась сделать вот так:

```
       <?php  $sql = "SELECT users FROM _kurusa";
              $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
              while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {    ?>
              <div id="name"> <?php echo $row?> </div>
       <?php } ?>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать это правильно и вообще можно ли так

$row, почему-то, Null, a $result - false. Хотя с таблицей SQL всё в порядке.

Вот, попыталась сделать ещё так:

```
$sql = "SELECT users FROM _kurusa";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<tr>";//ряд

echo "<td>". $row['users']. "</td>";

echo "</tr>";
}
   echo "</table>";
```

Спасибо всем за внимание. Знаете, этот вопрос был настолько глуп, что аж смешно) Вся проблема была в моей невнимательности - я написала название те той таблицы

Comment: Ну так, `$row` - это массив, делайте так `echo $row['photo'];` и вообще используйте `mysqli_fetch_assoc`.

Comment: @And, нет, так не работает

Comment: Если $result false то проверяйте на ошибки http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.error.php

Comment: @Біпач `можно ли вывести данные с SQL таблицы в див с определенной id?` - это делается по условию: [смотреть код](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/69dfb10808fc6abee443909af94334a2f1c54655)

Comment: Вы видимо не правильно, что-то делаете. Не может быть, так, чтобы не работало. Проверяйте на ошибки, желательно добавляйте в свой вопрос.

Comment: @And, нет-нет, уже всё работает) Всё дело было в моей невнимательности - я указала не ту табличку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы все делаете правильно!

1. Экранируйте название колонок и таблицы "SELECT `users` FROM `_kurusa`"
2. `$row` - это массив а не строка
3. id должны быть уникальны

**Итог:**

```
<?php  
  $sql = "SELECT `users` FROM `_kurusa`";
  $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {    ?>
  <div class="name"><?=$row['users']?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: На будущее - переходите на PHP PDO

Comment: Зачем? `mysqli` норм.

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/137664/ для @And

Comment: О том, что `PDO` имеет 12 драйверов для баз данных, а `mysqli` 1 драйвер, оба имеют ООП - это понятно, а вот `mysqli`, также имеет процедурный подход, для новичка будет понятнее

Answer (score 0):

У вас `$row` - массив, необходимо пробежаться по нему и вывести, как-то так

```
foreach($row as $current) {
   echo $current;
}
```

Comment: И так тоже не работает

Comment: @Біпач тогда покажите var_dump вашего $row, чтобы иметь представление что в нем лежит, точнее добавьте в вопрос